# WP Bakery columns not aligning horizontally

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create columns on a page in Wordpress using WP Bakery but somehow they won't align horizontally. I'm using Wordpress 4.9.8

The following image shows what I see using the "Frontend editor":

[image: Expected result]

This image shows what I see when I reload the page (after saving of course):

[image: Result]

Could anyone help me out solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an over-arching setting with your page.

Are you using template to design the page?  If you are, perhaps that template is reserving 50% of your page for a certain section/sidebar.

Check the overall page settings for anything that may suggest this.